# Как поменять размер шрифта в консоли с++?

Tags: visual-c++, шрифты, c++, консоль

Как поменять размер шрифта в консоли с++?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);  // Получить консоль

CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX fontInfo;
GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(hConsole, TRUE, &fontInfo); // Получить текущий шрифт

// Поменять какие-то параметры
wcsncpy(L"Arial Cyr", fontInfo.FaceName, LF_FACESIZE);  // Имя
fontInfo.dwFontSize.X = 10; // Размер (в логических единицах)

SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(hConsole, TRUE, &fontInfo); // Установить новый
```

Comment: renefator, большое спасибо!!!

Answer (score 3):

Cудя по тегу  VC++ то консоль виндовая...

Поменять программно или ручками?

Еесли ручками то ПКМ на чёрном значке окна консоли (вверху слева) и там свойства