# Изменить размер шрифта в Windows консоли CMD.exe

Tags: c++, windows, cmd, консоль, шрифты

Как изменить размер шрифта в Windows консоли `CMD.exe` не изменяя при этом размер окна?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как поменять размер шрифта в консоли с++?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/243596/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d1%88%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81)

Comment: не совсем! размер окна не должен изменяться

Comment: Ну так надо пропорционально число колонок и строк уменьшить. Но что-то сомнительно, что оно прям точно совпадёт.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Простой ответ - никак.
Причина в том, что `cmd.exe` не поддерживает изначально **программное** изменение шрифта в консоли.

Сложных пути - три:
Первый - сделать не консольное, а оконное приложение и добавить аналог TMemo (зависит от граф. библиотеки)

Второй вариант: 
Изменить параметры консоли в реестре.
Запустить окно программы и при выходе вернуть обратно.

Третий - поставить новую консоль (MSYS2) и изменить в соответствии с докупентацией.
Также можно использовать новую консоль (Windows terminal) и править json файл конфига.
P.S.
**В комментах предложили способ управления захватом окна** - на мой взгляб - это от лукавого, т.к. **данный способ перехватывает контроллы Windows (которые к тому же устарели и остались скорее для обратной совместимости**) и управляет окном. Вообще **перехват контроллов - жутко нестабильная и лагучая вещь, т.к. оконный менеджер начинает испытывать нештатные ситуации**.

Comment: У каждого окна консоли есть параметры шрифта и размера, которые доступны через контекстное меню заголовка. Ими же можно управлять через winapi, а в C# размеры вообще отлично доступны. Так что ответ про отсутствие поддержки такого в `cmd.exe` явно преувеличен.

Comment: @Qwertiy это параметры окна в оконном менеджере - про это уже написал в P.S.

Comment: Нет, реестр меняет для всех консолей, а у каждой отдельной консоли есть все те же параметры независимо от других.

Comment: теперь я понял, что консоль реально ограничена. Жаль. Тогда нужно мне рассмотреть sfml!

Comment: msys разве устанавливает новую консоль?

Comment: Безнадежно плохо сформулированный вопрос. Я бы за него жирный минус поставил.  Шрифт консоли cmd отлично меняется в его настройках, но  чего хочет реально топикстартер - непонятно.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду шрифт отлично меняется в свойствах? Он то меняется, но размер окна соответственно тоже меняется.

Comment: @user7860670 да, ставит новую, НО! не удаляет старую. У MSYS2 раньше было внутреннее API взаимодействия, которое можно использовать в том числе для решения данной задачи.

Comment: @Qwertiy я написал - см. в разделе P.S. Изменение параметров отдельного окна из вне (а использование HANDLE в примере в комментариях к вопросу как раз и обращение из вне к окну через контроллы) это очень плохая идея. Использование конроллов оправдано в очень-очень редких случаях. И украшательство, на мой взгляд, не является таковым случаем.

Comment: @ТарасПрограммер консоль действительно очень ограничена. Именно поэтому Microsoft сейчас пилят новую консоль

Comment: @ТарасПрограммер Если же вы хотите не менять размер окна и идти по кривой дорожке перехвата окна - можете перед изменением окна считать его размеры, изменить шрифт и изменить размер на исходный

Comment: А где в msys найти эту новую консоль?

Comment: Lmao. Нашёл способ! Сначала, перевести консоль в полноекранный режим, затем уменьшить/увеличить шрифт, потом обратно перевести консоль в нормальний размер. Вуаля!